# Getting python Numba working on Ubuntu 14.10 or Fedora 21 with python 2.7

Tags: linux, python-2.7, fedora, numba, ubuntu-14.10

Recently, I have had a frustrating time to get python Numba working on Ubuntu or Fedora Linux. The main problem has been with the compilation of llvmlite. What do I need to install for these to compile properly?

Comment: Thank you very much for this post. I asked a question about this few days ago but I did not go an answer (on askubuntu). I will try your solution in 10 hours by now and let you know if it works on my Ubuntu

Comment: I wish I can invite you for a nice dinner. You really saved me from death. Thank you very much for this solution that does not exist anywhere.

Answer (score 24):

The versions I got working at the end were numba-0.17.0 (also 0.18.2) and llvmlite-0.2.2 (also 0.4.0). Here are the relevant dependencies and configuration options on Ubuntu and Fedora.

**For Ubuntu 14.04 *Trusty)**

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev libedit libedit-dev llvm-3.8 llvm-3.8-dev llvm-dev
sudo pip install enum34 funcsigs
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.8 pip install llvmlite --user
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.8 pip install numba --user
```

**For Ubuntu 14.10**

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev libedit libedit-dev llvm-3.5 llvm-3.5-dev llvm-dev
pip install enum34 funcsigs
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.5 pip install llvmlite
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.5 pip install numba
```

**For Ubuntu 15.04**

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev libedit2 libedit-dev llvm-3.6 llvm-3.6-dev llvm-dev
pip install enum34 funcsigs
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.6 pip install llvmlite
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.6 pip install numba
```

**For Fedora 21**

```
yum install zlib zlib-devel libstdc++-devel libstdc++ libstdc++-static llvm-3.5.0 llvm-devel-3.5.0 libedit libedit-devel
pip install enum34 funcsigs
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config pip install llvmlite
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config pip install numba
```

<sub>Note: this was originally posted by the OP in the question—moved here to keep this fit for SO.</sub>

Comment: Some library names are a bit different for Ubuntu 14.04.  Updating the commands to include them below:

sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev libedit2 libedit-dev llvm-3.5 llvm-3.5-dev llvm-dev
sudo pip install enum34 funcsigs
sudo LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.5 pip install llvmlite
sudo LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.5 pip install numba

Comment: Anybody knows how to make this work for Ubuntu 15.04? I tried the 14.10 instruction above and yet it still fails at 'pip install llvmlite'

Comment: This doesn't work for Ubuntu 12.04 as well. Gets stuck in compilation of llvmlite :(

Comment: For Ubuntu 15.04 I switched from llvm 3.5 to llvm 3.6 and things seem to work. So for example, run "LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.6 pip install llvmlite" instead.

Answer (score 4):

### For ubuntu 15.10

fisrt check that pip has the correct version:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade wheel
```

pip >= 8.1

```
$ pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from
$ wheel version
wheel 0.29.0
```

apt-get install llvm stuff:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev libedit2 libedit-dev
sudo apt-get install llvm-3.7 llvm-3.7-dev llvm-dev
```

and then with pip (warning llvmlite work only with llvm 3.7):

```
pip install enum34 funcsigs
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.7 pip install llvmlite
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.7 pip install numba
```

Comment: This also works for 16.04. In my case, I used python 2.7 and llvm 3.8 (which is compatible with  llvmlite 0.13).

Answer (score 3):

### Ubuntu 15.10 using Python 3.4.3+

**llvmlite version 0.9 or newer (I installed 0.10)**

As stated in [llvmlite's GitHub Page](https://github.com/numba/llvmlite):

> As of version 0.9, llvmlite requires LLVM 3.7. It does not support earlier or later versions of LLVM.

**My solution, similar to the ones in other answers (but regarding python3):**

To meet [the dependencies](http://llvmlite.pydata.org/en/latest/install/index.html#prerequisites-unix): (like `libedit` and compression libraries)

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev libedit2 libedit-dev
sudo pip3 install enum34 funcsigs
```

**llvm-3.7** (Other answers included llvm package, which nowadays installs version 3.6, not working)

```
sudo apt-get install llvm-3.7 llvm-3.7-dev llvm-3.7-runtime llvm-3.7-tools
```

Trying to install **llvmlite** from **pip**:

```
sudo pip3 install llvmlite
```

*(If it works, skip this)* 
If it doesn't work, like in my case, build the last master branch from their repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/numba/llvmlite
cd llvmlite/
sudo ch -c "LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/config-3.7 python3 setup.py build
sudo sh -c "LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.7 python3 setup.py install"
```

Finally, install **numba**:

```
sudo pip3 install numba
```

Comment: I'm not sure but the question clearly states using phyton 2.7 Also you have a **huge** formatting (bold...) problem.

Comment: @cramopy I provided my solution for Python3, since I've had the same issue and there weren't any other stackoverflow questions regarding it.

For the python 2.7 case , instead of `pip3` and `python3`, the use is `pip` and `python`.

Sorry for the poor formatting. Thought it could provide some visual aid for future users' troubleshooting.

In the meanwhile, I've found [this guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers) to improve my experience here. (1st time I answered something )

Comment: `ch` should be `sh` in example.

Comment: typo: that probably should be `sudo sh -c "LLVM...` not `sudo ch  -c "LLVM...`

Answer (score 2):

There was a change in llvmlite. Since version llvmlite-0.6.0 llvm-3.6 is required. The correct installation is now:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev libedit2 libedit-dev llvm-3.6 llvm-3.6-dev llvm-dev
pip install enum34 funcsigs
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.6 pip install llvmlite
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.6 pip install numba
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially I didn't get it working with the comments here and then I found out: 1. meanwhile llvm 3.6 instead of 3.5 is needed and 2. for me the `LLVM_CONFIG` env variable doesn't work. So I installed numba like this:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev libedit-dev llvm-3.6 llvm-3.6-dev llvm-3.6-runtime llvm-3.6-tools
sudo pip install enum34 funcsigs
sudo mv /usr/bin/llvm-config /usr/bin/llvm-config_bak
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-config-3.6 /usr/bin/llvm-config
sudo pip install llvmlite
sudo pip install numba
sudo mv /usr/bin/llvm-config_bak /usr/bin/llvm-config
```

(Tried on Ubuntu 14.04.)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me. In all cases when I try to install `llvmlite` by `pip` it fails with `error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized`. Any idea? I have been trying to install `numba` for the past 4 hours unsuccessfully so far.

Answer (score 1):

## **For Fedora 23**

First check that you have the latest `pip` version:

```
pip install -U pip
pip install -U wheel
```

Then install the following pacakges:

```
dnf install zlib zlib-devel libstdc++-devel libstdc++ libstdc++-static llvm-3.7.0 llvm-devel-3.7.0 libedit libedit-devel
pip install enum34 funcsigs
```

Then download and unzip [`llvmlite`](https://github.com/numba/llvmlite) from the GIT repository. Suppose that you are downloading to `/usr/local/llvmlite` then:

```
git clone <address-for-llvmlite.git> /usr/local/llvmlite
cd /usr/local/llvmlite
```

Build source as described [here](http://llvmlite.pydata.org/en/latest/install/index.html):

```
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config python setupy.py build
```

Refresh terminal session and install built `llvmlite`

```
reset
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config python setup.py install
```

Finally download and install `numba` by

```
pip install numba
```

Answer (score 0):

## For Ubuntu 16.04:

```
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.7 pip install llvmlite
```

Comment: this doesn't work. It explicitly complains that 3.9 is needed

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu 16.04**

```
sudo pip3 install llvmlite
```

explicitly requests llvm version 3.9.

But in the official packages, there is (currently) only llvm up to version 3.8.
The solution is to install it like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787383/how-to-install-llvm-3-9)

Then you can run `LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.9 sudo pip3 install llvmlite`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else recently had this problem, according to their [github page...](https://github.com/numba/llvmlite)

"llvmlite works with Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 or greater.
As of version 0.17.0, llvmlite requires LLVM 4.0. It does not support earlier or later versions of LLVM.

They have a compatibility table of what works with what. All recent packages can be gotten from [their webpage.](http://apt.llvm.org/)

Answer (score 0):

For **Ubuntu 14.04** I managed to install with this:

```
export LDFLAGS="-std=gnu++11 -fPIC"

LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-7 pip install llvmlite

LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-7 pip install numba
```