# Cannot install python numba dependency llvmlite on Fedora 21 system

Tags: python, numba

I am trying to install python numba on PC running Fedora 21. I'm running Python 2.7.8.

I've found some useful information on [Getting python Numba working on Ubuntu 14.10 or Fedora 21 with python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782512/getting-python-numba-working-on-ubuntu-14-10-or-fedora-21-with-python-2-7) and tried what was suggested there but it did not work in my case. What was suggested for that particular query was

```
yum install zlib zlib-devel libstdc++-devel libstdc++ libstdc++-static llvm-3.5.0 llvm-devel-3.5.0 libedit libedit-devel
pip install enum34
pip install funcsigs
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config pip install llvmlite
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config pip install numba
```

The problem occurs during (step 4 above) the installation of llvmlite. 
Here are some of the messages I see in the terminal window when running the pip install llmvlite

```
Downloading/unpacking llvmlite
Downloading llvmlite-0.2.2.tar.gz (75kB): 75kB downloaded
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-1eUon1/llvmlite/setup.py) egg_info for package llvmlite

Installing collected packages: llvmlite
Running setup.py install for llvmlite
got version from file /tmp/pip-build-1eUon1/llvmlite/llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.2.2', 'full': 'c6e72f55cb10bccdcba2f31e9d52c528b12c5a0e'}
/usr/bin/python /tmp/pip-build-1eUon1/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
LLVM version... 3.5.0
# static-libstdc++ avoids runtime dependencies on a
# particular libstdc++ version.
g++ -static-libstdc++ -shared -flto `/usr/bin/llvm-config --cxxflags` -fno-rtti assembly.cpp bitcode.cpp core.cpp initfini.cpp module.cpp value.cpp executionengine.cpp transforms.cpp passmanagers.cpp targets.cpp dylib.cpp linker.cpp -o libllvmlite.so -flto `/usr/bin/llvm-config --ldflags` -Wl,--exclude-libs=ALL `/usr/bin/llvm-config --system-libs --libs all`
/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMLineEditor
/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMInstrumentation
/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMProfileData
/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMIRReader
/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMAsmParser
/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMDebugInfo
/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMOption
/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMJIT
```

etc...(have not included full list of cannot find messages)

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Makefile.linux:17: recipe for target 'libllvmlite.so' failed

make: *** [libllvmlite.so] Error 1

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/pip-build-mmSawV/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 112, in <module>

    main()

  File "/tmp/pip-build-mmSawV/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 104, in main

    main_posix('linux', '.so')

  File "/tmp/pip-build-mmSawV/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 96, in main_posix

    subprocess.check_call(['make', '-f', makefile])

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call

    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make', '-f', 'Makefile.linux']' returned non-zero exit status 2

error: command '/usr/bin/python' failed with exit status 1
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Regards,

Will.

Answer (score 2):

Just fixed this problem of compiling llvmlite on Fedora 21. You need to install first the static libraries of LLVM (llvm-static package in yum). This will install the LLVMLineEditor, etc. libraries in /usr/lib64/llvm.