# Missing ch command ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782512/getting-python-numba-working-on-ubuntu-14-10-or-fedora-21-with-python-2-7) question to install numba on ubuntu 16.04.

At some point I need to run this command from the terminal:

```
sudo ch -c "LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/config-3.7 python3 setup.py build"
```

However the terminal says that the ch command doesn't exist.

It seems I cannot install the command by `sudo apt-get install ch`

How shall I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `sh` instead of `ch`.

Comment: No, I formatted the computer and in the previous installation this command worked

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you use? In any case, it appears that the question has been put on hold as off-topic, so I suggest asking the question on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).